# Android Tic tac toe - After the computer wins, the player can still use the buttons, and wins

Tags: java, android

i'm a new android programmer, and i need your help..
As I said problem is after the computer wins, the player can still use the buttons, and wins..

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.qwert.graox;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int c[][];
    int i, j = 0;
    Button b[][];
    TextView textView;
    AI ai;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        setBoard();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.add("New Game");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        setBoard();
        return true;
    }


    // Set up the game board.
    private void setBoard() {
        ai = new AI();
        b = new Button[4][4];
        c = new int[4][4];


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogi);


        b[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


        b[2][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);


        b[3][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b[3][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        b[3][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                c[i][j] = 2;
        }


        textView.setText("Press any key to start");
        textView.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);


        // add the click listeners for each button
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                b[i][j].setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(i, j));
                if(!b[i][j].isEnabled()) {
                    b[i][j].setText("-");
                    b[i][j].setTextColor(0xff000000);
                    b[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        int x;
        int y;


        public MyClickListener(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (b[x][y].isEnabled()); {
                b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                b[x][y].setText("O");
                b[x][y].setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF );
                c[x][y] = 0;
                textView.setText("");
                if (!checkBoard()) {
                    ai.takeTurn();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private class AI {
        public void takeTurn() {
            if(c[1][1]==2 &&
                    ((c[1][2]==0 && c[1][3]==0) ||
                            (c[2][2]==0 && c[3][3]==0) ||
                            (c[2][1]==0 && c[3][1]==0))) {
                markSquare(1,1);
            } else if (c[1][2]==2 &&
                    ((c[2][2]==0 && c[3][2]==0) ||
                            (c[1][1]==0 && c[1][3]==0))) {
                markSquare(1,2);
            } else if(c[1][3]==2 &&
                    ((c[1][1]==0 && c[1][2]==0) ||
                            (c[3][1]==0 && c[2][2]==0) ||
                            (c[2][3]==0 && c[3][3]==0))) {
                markSquare(1,3);
            } else if(c[2][1]==2 &&
                    ((c[2][2]==0 && c[2][3]==0) ||
                            (c[1][1]==0 && c[3][1]==0))){
                markSquare(2,1);
            } else if(c[2][2]==2 &&
                    ((c[1][1]==0 && c[3][3]==0) ||
                            (c[1][2]==0 && c[3][2]==0) ||
                            (c[3][1]==0 && c[1][3]==0) ||
                            (c[2][1]==0 && c[2][3]==0))) {
                markSquare(2,2);
            } else if(c[2][3]==2 &&
                    ((c[2][1]==0 && c[2][2]==0) ||
                            (c[1][3]==0 && c[3][3]==0))) {
                markSquare(2,3);
            } else if(c[3][1]==2 &&
                    ((c[1][1]==0 && c[2][1]==0) ||
                            (c[3][2]==0 && c[3][3]==0) ||
                            (c[2][2]==0 && c[1][3]==0))){
                markSquare(3,1);
            } else if(c[3][2]==2 &&
                    ((c[1][2]==0 && c[2][2]==0) ||
                            (c[3][1]==0 && c[3][3]==0))) {
                markSquare(3,2);
            }else if( c[3][3]==2 &&
                    ((c[1][1]==0 && c[2][2]==0) ||
                            (c[1][3]==0 && c[2][3]==0) ||
                            (c[3][1]==0 && c[3][2]==0))) {
                markSquare(3,3);
            } else {
                Random rand = new Random();

                int a = rand.nextInt(4);
                int b = rand.nextInt(4);
                while(a==0 || b==0 || c[a][b]!=2) {
                    a = rand.nextInt(4);
                    b = rand.nextInt(4);
                }
                markSquare(a,b);
            }
        }


        private void markSquare(int x, int y) {
            b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
            b[x][y].setText("X");
            b[x][y].setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
            c[x][y] = 1;
            checkBoard();
        }
    }

    // check the board to see if someone has won
    private boolean checkBoard() {
        boolean gameOver = false;
        if ((c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)
                || (c[1][2] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[1][2] == 0 && c[1][3] == 0)
                || (c[2][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0)
                || (c[3][1] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][1] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)) {
            textView.setText("Super - you Win");
            gameOver = true;
        } else if ((c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)
                || (c[1][2] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1)
                || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[1][2] == 1 && c[1][3] == 1)
                || (c[2][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1)
                || (c[3][1] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][1] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)) {
            textView.setText("GameOver. Computer wins..");
            gameOver = true;
        } else {
            boolean empty = false;
            for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                for(j=1; j<=3; j++) {
                    if(c[i][j]==2) {
                        empty = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!empty) {
                gameOver = true;
                textView.setText("Game Over. Draft!");
            }
        }
        return gameOver;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is somewhere there:

```
// check the board to see if someone has won
private boolean checkBoard() {
    boolean gameOver = false;
    if ((c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
            || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)
            || (c[1][2] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0)
            || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
            || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[1][2] == 0 && c[1][3] == 0)
            || (c[2][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0)
            || (c[3][1] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
            || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][1] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)) {
        textView.setText("Super - you Win");
        gameOver = true;
    } else if ((c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
            || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)
            || (c[1][2] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1)
            || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
            || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[1][2] == 1 && c[1][3] == 1)
            || (c[2][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1)
            || (c[3][1] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
            || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][1] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)) {
        textView.setText("GameOver. Computer wins..");
        gameOver = true;
    } else {
        boolean empty = false;
        for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            for(j=1; j<=3; j++) {
                if(c[i][j]==2) {
                    empty = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!empty) {
            gameOver = true;
            textView.setText("Game Over. Draft!");
        }
    }
    return gameOver;
}
```

Comment: gameOver never used!! what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button have option setClickable.

```
if(!empty) {
   gameOver = true;
   textView.setText("Game Over. Draft!");

   for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                b[i][j].setClickable(false); // button object
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is there

```
public void onClick(View view) { 
    if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
        b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
        b[x][y].setText("O");
        b[x][y].setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF );
        c[x][y] = 0;
        textView.setText("");
        if (!checkBoard()) {
            ai.takeTurn();
        }
    }
}
```

Player alway can touch button

best way is you gameOver be field and check in onClick if statment